# Isometric camera lookat

Tags: mathematics, matrix, directx12, camera3d

I'm trying to make my isometric camera follow my player or lookat any other object

projection matrix is

```
XMMatrixOrthographicRH(_size * _aspectRatio, _size, _minZ, _maxZ);
```

view matrix is

```
void setIsometricEye(XMVECTOR_eye, float _x, float _z)
{
    XMMATRIX t  = XMMatrixTranslationFromVector(XMVectorNegate(_eye));
    XMMATRIX rx = XMMatrixRotationX(toRad(_x));
    XMMATRIX rz = XMMatrixRotationZ(toRad(_z));
    XMMATRIX view   = XMMatrixMultiply(t, XMMatrixMultiply(rz, rx));
}
```

eye calculation

```
void setIsometricTarget(XMVECTOR _target, float _x, float _z, float _distance)
{
XMMATRIX rx = XMMatrixRotationX(toRad(_x));
XMMATRIX rz = XMMatrixRotationZ(toRad(_z));
XMMATRIX r   = XMMatrixMultiply(rz, rx);
XMVECTOR d   = XMVector3TransformNormal(VecForward,r);
XMVECTOR eye = XMVectorSubtract(_target, d);
setIsometricEye(eye,_x,_z);
}
```

But the object/player don't stay in the center of the screen. What can I be missing here?

thanks